# Overloading namespaces in xml with envelope

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, envelope

I have a program that iterates through XML Documents to search for values.
I want to extract the version number of the document I found and add it to the search result.

The problem I encounter is, that the documents have a lot of different namespaces, and most of them have an envelope. The envelope has the same namespaceprefix like the divergent namespace in the payload of the document.
I am struggeling to extract values from the payload, because I am not able to get the namespace of the inner document.

```
if (myX != null)
{
    XNamespace myNs;
    if (myX.Root.FirstAttribute == null)
        myNs = "";
    else
    {
        myNs = myX.Root.FirstAttribute.Value;
        var dummy2 = myX.Root.Descendants("Message").First().FirstAttribute;
        var dummy1 = myX.Root.Descendants(myNs + "Message").First().FirstAttribute;

    }


    foreach (XNode xN in myX.Root.DescendantNodes())
    {
        if (xN is XElement)
        {
            if (!wildcard)
            {
                if (((XElement)xN).Value == value)
                {
                    myResultSet[0].Add(new ResultSet(file, myX.Root.Descendants(myNs + "MessageVersion").First().Value));
                }
            }
            else if (wildcard)
            {
                if (((XElement)xN).Value.Contains(value))
                {
                    myResultSet[0].Add(new ResultSet(file, myX.Root.Descendants(myNs + "MessageVersion").First().Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the ns0:Body Element, but I fail to get anything with the "http://dummy.schema.com/ss2/schemas/2.5/DESADV" namespace.
The XML is something like this:

```
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://dummy.schema.com/ss2/schemas/2.3">
  <ns0:SenderILN>123456789123</ns0:SenderILN>
  <ns0:ReceiverILN>987654321987</ns0:ReceiverILN>
  <ns0:EnvelopeNumber>12345</ns0:EnvelopeNumber>
  <ns0:Body>
    <ns0:Message xmlns:ns0="http://dummy.schema.com/ss2/schemas/2.5/DESADV">
      <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:MessageType>DESADV</ns0:MessageType>
        <ns0:SenderILN>123456789123</ns0:SenderILN>1
        <ns0:ReceiverILN>987654321987</ns0:ReceiverILN>
        <ns0:MessageVersion>2.5</ns0:MessageVersion>
      </ns0:Header>
      <ns0:DESADV>
        <ns0:Payload />
      </ns0:DESADV>
    </ns0:Message>
  </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

Is there a possibility to get to the inner message without removing the envelope first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to 'extract' the namespace. The namespace is part of the element name - just as you know the local name `MessageVersion` you should also know its namespace.

You should be doing something like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://dummy.schema.com/ss2/schemas/2.5/DESADV"

var version = (string) doc
    .Descendants(ns + "MessageVersion")
    .Single();
```

If for some reason you don't know or don't care about the namespace, you can just search by local name:

```
var version = (string) doc
    .Descendants()
    .Single(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MessageVersion");
```

Comment: The first solution is not suitable, because there are dozen of different documents with different namespaces - it would be a pain in the ass to manually update a namespacelist. The second solution returns an Exception: "Sequence contains no data" on the same file my extended code as answer (below) returned the value. I get this exception too, if I dont use the correct namespace in my code, thats why I am so obsessed with the namespace. ;)

Comment: @kurdy I suppose that's reasonable. I'm a little surprised all these documents with different namespaces all have the same `MessageVersion` element, however. I'm not sure re your error - you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uK0BGr) that the code works with your example. *Note, I noticed the example didn't compile - but I assume you'd fixed this. I've updated the code.*.

Comment: That is indeed suspicious. I will test it with the original file and write back if I know more.

Comment: The reason it did not work in the first place was stupid me. Your code works and I feel incredible stupid again :-\. Thanks for your help. The question why the MessageVersion always exist, is that each of my messages have an identical header section.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((XElement)xN).Value == value)
{
    XNamespace myNs = ((XElement)xN).Name.Namespace;
    myResultSet[0].Add(new ResultSet(file, myX.Root.Descendants(myNs + "MessageVersion").First().Value));
}
```

After starting from the result and not the document itself it was quite easy to extract the namespace and the value.

But this works only, because I am brute forcing the document. I found no solution to do it in a sober way... Still looking for a better solution.